# Schedule a worker in Gearman for a specific date and time

Tags: php, cron, gearman

I need to send all emails from my site once per hour. For this purpose I plan to use Gearman worker.

Is it possible to schedule a worker launch time right in the Gearman without external Cron task ? Does Gearman provide such kind of functionality ?

Comment: No, Gearman doesn't do this. Use cron for scheduled tasks.